How to center a contents of a Frame within Tab in Tkinter
I have a program with 2 tabs. Second tab is wider - let's say it is set to be 600 px.
That's why I guess I have an extra space on the right on the first tab.

How can I center contents of the first tab on the screen?
Is it possible to have resizable tabs - I mean that when I switch to desired tab the window of the program will automatically change size?
Code:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

# Tabs
my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack(pady=15)

frame1 = Frame(my_notebook, bg="blue")
frame2 = Frame(my_notebook)

frame1.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

my_notebook.add(frame1, text="111")
my_notebook.add(frame2, text="222")

### first tab

my_input = Entry(frame1, width = 50)
my_input.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=20)

drop_input = Button(frame1, text = "drop_input", width = 15)
drop_input.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,10))

my_button = Button(frame1, text = "button", width = 15)
my_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady = (10,10))

### second tab

f1 = Frame(frame2, width=600, height = 10)
f1.pack_propagate(False)
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

label1 = Label(f1, text="xxx").pack()

root.mainloop()


To center those widgets, you can create another frame and create those widgets as children of that frame. Then pack this frame at the center of top side:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Tabs
my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack(pady=15)

frame1 = tk.Frame(my_notebook, bg="blue")
frame2 = tk.Frame(my_notebook)

my_notebook.add(frame1, text="111")
my_notebook.add(frame2, text="222")

### first tab

# create another frame and pack it at the center of top side
frame1_1 = tk.Frame(frame1, bg=frame1['bg'])
frame1_1.pack()

# create those widgets inside that frame
my_input = tk.Entry(frame1_1, width = 50)
my_input.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=20)

drop_input = tk.Button(frame1_1, text = "drop_input", width = 15)
drop_input.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,10))

my_button = tk.Button(frame1_1, text = "button", width = 15)
my_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady = (10,10))

### second tab

f1 = tk.Frame(frame2, width=600, height = 10)
f1.pack_propagate(False)
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

label1 = tk.Label(f1, text="xxx").pack()

root.mainloop()

Result:


To resize the window dynamically when switching tab, you can change the width and height of the notebook widget after switching tab, i.e. inside the callback of virtual event <<NotebookTabChanged>>:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def on_tab_changed(event):
    event.widget.update_idletasks()
    # get the frame of current selected tab
    frame = event.widget.nametowidget(event.widget.select())
    # resize the notebook to the size of the frame
    event.widget.config(width=frame.winfo_reqwidth(), height=frame.winfo_reqheight())

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Tabs
my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
my_notebook.pack(pady=15)
my_notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", on_tab_changed)

frame1 = tk.Frame(my_notebook, bg="blue")
frame2 = tk.Frame(my_notebook)

my_notebook.add(frame1, text="111")
my_notebook.add(frame2, text="222")

### first tab

# create those widgets inside that frame
my_input = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 50)
my_input.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=20)

drop_input = tk.Button(frame1, text = "drop_input", width = 15)
drop_input.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,10))

my_button = tk.Button(frame1, text = "button", width = 15)
my_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady = (10,10))

### second tab

f1 = tk.Frame(frame2, width=600, height = 10)
f1.pack_propagate(False)
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

label1 = tk.Label(f1, text="xxx").pack()

root.mainloop()

Result:


